# Kotlin: gettng rid of Unchecked casts for Comparable

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have just implemented selection sort to get acquainted with Kotlin and bumped into an unchecked cast which I am finding difficult to get rid of. The implementation is based on the `kotlin.Comparable` interface:

```
object SelectionSort {

    fun <T> sort(a: Array<Comparable<T>>) {
        val N = a.size
        for(i in 0..N - 2) {
            var min = i
            for(j in i + 1..N - 1) {
                if(less(a[j], a[min])) {
                    min = j
                }
            }
            exchange(a, i, min)
        }
    }

    private fun <T> exchange(a: Array<Comparable<T>>, i: Int, min: Int) {
        val temp = a[i]
        a[i] = a[min]
        a[min] = temp
    }

    private fun <T> less(comparable: Comparable<T>, comparable1: Comparable<T>): Boolean {
        return comparable < (comparable1 as T) // Here is the unchecked cast
    }
}
```

The exact message is "*Unchecked cast: `Comparable<T>` to `T`*".

My preference is to use the `kotlin.Comparable` interface as the main argument of the `sort` method as well of the helper methods. But how is it possible to compare a generic comparable to another one in a clean way? 
If this is not possible, what would be a clean alternative to implement something like selection sort using interfaces?

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45908484/2735286), I have re-written my selection sort implementation:

```
object SelectionSort {

    fun <T : Comparable<T>> sort(a: Array<T>) {
        val N = a.size
        for (i in 0..N - 2) {
            var min = i
            for (j in i + 1..N - 1) {
                if (less(a[j], a[min])) {
                    min = j
                }
            }
            exchange(a, i, min)
        }
    }

    fun <T> exchange(a: Array<T>, i: Int, min: Int) {
        val temp = a[i]
        a[i] = a[min]
        a[min] = temp
    }

    fun <T : Comparable<T>> less(c1: T, c2: T) =
            c1 < c2
}
```

This implementation has now no warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a bound `<T : Comparable<T>>` on `sort` and `less`.

```
fun <T : Comparable<T>> sort(arr: Array<T>) = ...
fun <T : Comparable<T>> less(l: T, r: T) = ...
```

There's no reason to resort to reified types when it works just fine without.

Also, the parameter to `sort` *should not be* `Array<Comparable<T>>`. Arrays in Kotlin are *invariant*: if `A extends B`, `Array<A>` is not a subtype of `Array<B>`. This is unlike Java, where arrays are covariant and `String[]` is a subtype of `Object[]`. Invariance is the correct way. If you defined sort as it is now, you would not be able to write

```
val arr: Array<String> = ...
sort(arr);
```

because `sort` wants an `Array<Comparable<String>>` but `arr` is an `Array<String>`.

Also, there's no reason to place the extra bound on `exchange`

```
fun <T> exchange(arr: Array<T>, i: Int, j: Int) = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution to your Problem, but too complex

This solves your problem:

```
inline fun <reified T> less(c1: Comparable<T>, c2: Comparable<T>) =
   if (c2 is T) {
       c1 < c2
   } else {
       throw IllegalStateException() // whatever
   }
```

The cast is not necessary if you first check its type `T`. This is possible if `T` is made [reified](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters), i.e. you can access it at runtime (by default generic types are not available at runtime). This again is only possible if your `method` is [`inline`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html).
Note that accessing `c2` after the type check is possible *without explicit casting* because the compiler already knows you're doing safe stuff, this is called ["**Smart Cast**"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html).

This implementation is not 100% correct in terms of error handling as you can see - but that's up to you ;-)

BUT: Do not do it like this.

### Better Solution

I'd suggest you get rid of handling `Comparable` in your implementation, so that the `sort` method rather looks like this:

```
 fun <T: Comparable<T>> sort(a: Array<T>)
```

This ensures only `T`'s can be sorted that implement `Comparable`, which is expressed with `:` (upper bound) in the generic type. Then your `less` method looks like:

```
private fun <T : Comparable<T>> less(comparable: T, comparable1: T): Boolean {
    return comparable < comparable1
}
```

No cast necessary :-)

(Same applies to `exchange`)

Comment: Yep, the "better solution" is the way to go.

Comment: Yes it is. But I wanted to give you a solution for your casting problem too.